# Finding the number of elements, bijective function

Tags: functions

I have to determine the number of elements of set $A$ if a function  $f:A\times A \to P(A)$ exists and is bijective. I don't understand what $P(A)$ means, is it just the notation for the function? And how do I figure out the number of elements?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you sure $A$ is a "group" and not just a "set"?

Comment: It's a set. Sorry,english is not my first language.I've edited

Comment: Is the cardinality of $A$ allowed to be infinite?

Comment: It does not say in the exercise.I guess?

Answer (score 0):

$P(A)$ generally means the *power set* of $A$, which is the set of subsets of $A$. For example, if $A = \{1,2,3\}$ then $P(A) = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\},\{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$. In this case, if $|A| = n$, then $|P(A)| = 2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A)$ refers to the *power set* of $A$ which is the set consisting of all the subsets of $A$.

I'm assuming that you are referring to finite sets only.

If $|A|=n$, then $|A \times A|=n^2$ and $|P(A)|=2^n.$ (*Try to prove these)*.

For $f$ to be bijective, the number of elements in the domain and codomain must be equal.(Why?)

$$\therefore n^2=2^n$$

which has only one positive integral solution, $n=2$.